# Can ping localhost but can't browse

Tags: internet-explorer, ping, localhost

I know this is a pretty common question but I did my research and couldn't find a solution for this issue. I'm configuring a development application server and I came to the point where I can ping both localhost and 127.0.0.1, but I cannot browse either of them from IE or Firefox. I can browse and ping other websites (such as google) just fine.

I tried flushing the dns (ipconfig /flushdns), restarting the IIS Admin service, restarting IIS itself, etc, and nothing seems to work. The results from ipconfig /all shows IP Rounting Enabled = No and WINS Proxy Enabled = No. Hwat is intriguing to me is that I compared everything in IIS in the dev environment with the production environment and the settings are the same, but I can browse localhost in production, but not in dev!

What could be causing the inability to browse localhost and 127.0.0.1 from IE and Firefox?

Comment: what if you browse to your local IP (not localhost)

Comment: when you say can't browse, what do you mean? like can't browse a local web server? or can't do start \\ip   or can't browse the web  like google?

Comment: Is your dev server configured on port 80, and is port 80 open?

Comment: @Keltari: Browsing my local IP give the same result - HTTP Error 404 (but, again, pinging the IP works).

Comment: @barlop: what I mean is that if I open my browser (IE or Firefox) and type either localhost or my IP address and search, I will receive an HTTP error 404 - Not found. But if I use the browser for anything else (Google, email, etc), it's working (which means the problem is not with the browser itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:   Reset TCP/IP and Winsock > 
 right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
enter this command:

netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Restart the computer.

If that does not work try this command:

netsh winsock reset catalog

Comment: I ran the command netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt and restarted the machine, but now I can't login to the machine again :S

Comment: It turns out that when I ran netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt, the machine lost its IP address and I couldn't login. I had to ask a team member to fix that for me, and once I could log back in, nothing had changed: still same error when I try to browse.

Comment: I tried the second command, netsh winsock reset catalog, and it didn't work either.